# Identifying units in a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, proof-explanation, integral-domain

> **Problem Statement**: Let $R$ be a domain. Identify the units in $R[x]$.

I am trying to identify the units in a domain $R$ by considering an arbitrary element $a=a_{n}x^{n}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0}\in R[x]$ with an inverse $b=b_{m}x^{m}+\cdots+b_{1}x+b_{0}\in R[x]$.

If $b=a^{-1}$, then $$1=ab=ba=(a_{n}x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_{1}x+a_{0})(b_{m}x^{m}+b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+b_{1}x+b_{0})
 = (a_{n}b_{m}x^{n+m}+a_{n}b_{m-1}x^{n+m-1}+\cdots+a_{n}b_{1}x^{n+1}+a_{n}b_{0}x^{n})
+ (a_{n-1}b_{m}x^{n+m-1}+a_{n-1}b_{m-1}x^{n+m-2}+\cdots+a_{n-1}b_{1}x^{n}+a_{n-1}b_{0}x^{n-1})+\cdots
+ (a_{1}b_{m}x^{m+1}+a_{1}b_{m-1}x^{m}+\cdots+a_{1}b_{1}x^{2}+a_{1}b_{0}x)
+(a_{0}b_{m}x^{m}+a_{0}b_{m-1}x^{m-1}+\cdots+a_{0}b_{1}x+a_{0}b_{0})$$

$$= a_{n}b_{m}x^{m+n}+(a_{n}b_{m-1}+a_{n-1}b_{m})x^{n+m-1} +
 (a_{n}b_{m-2}+a_{n-1}b_{m-1}+a_{n-2}b_{m})x^{n+m-2}+\cdots+(a_{2}b_{0}+a_{1}b_{1}+a_{0}b_{2})x^{2}+(a_{1}b_{0}+a_{0}b_{1})x+a_0b_0$$
Thus,
$$a_{n}b_{m}=a_{n}b_{m-1}+a_{n-1}b_{m}=a_{n}b_{m-2}+a_{n-1}b_{m-1}+a_{n-2}b_{m}=\cdots=a_{2}b_{0}+a_{1}b_{1}+a_{0}b_{2}=a_{1}b_{0}+a_{0}b_{1}=0$$
Or more generally,
$$a_{i}b_{0}+a_{i-1}b_{1}+\cdots+a_{1}b_{i-1}+a_{0}b_{i}=0$$
and
$$a_{0}b_{0}=1.$$

Since $R$ is a domain, $R[x]$ is a domain, and thus, $a_{n}b_{m}=0$ implies that $a_{n}=0$ or $b_{m} =0$.

If $a_{n}=0$ and $b_{m}\neq0$, then it would recursively follow that $a_{n}=0\ \Rightarrow a_{n-1}=0$?
Similarly, If $b_{m}=0$ and $a_{n}\neq0$, then it would recursively follow that $b_{m}=0\ \Rightarrow b_{m-1}=0$?

But that would imply that either $a_{0}=0$ or $b_{0} = 0$, which is an issue, because we want $a_{0}b_{0}=1$.

I am thinking that the only units are constant polynomials? That is, unless there is some positive integer $k$ such that $x^{k}=0$. Should I be considering that case as well, or is there an easier way to approach this problem?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your proof is close to correct, but you're making this *much* harder than it needs to be. Just use "degrees".

First, prove that, given two non-zero polynomials, the degree of $fg$ is the degree of $f$ $+$ the degree of $g$. [Here you'll need that $R$ is a domain so that leading coefficients don't collapse.]

Next, notice that for a unit $u(x)u^{-1}(x)=1$, so the degree of $u$ and $u^{-1}$ must sum to the degree of $1$ (which is $0$). The only way for this to happen is if the degree of $u$ (and $u^{-1}$) is $0$. It's a constant!

Thus units must be constants. Now the rest is details. In the end you should get that the units of $R[x]$ are exactly the units of $R$. :)

Comment: Ah, so my conjecture was correct. Basically I can consider arbitrary polynomials of degree $n$ and $m$ respectively, such that the leading coefficients are non-zero, and use them to prove that the degree of their product is $m+n$. Then the rest of your suggestion makes complete sense (showing that the units must be constant polynomials). This proof strategy does seem *much* less complicated than mine. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: if $R$ is a domain, then $\deg{fg} = \deg{f} + \deg{g}$ for all polynomials $f, g\in R[x]$.